# Socket connection using BufferedReader / BufferedWriter

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

My server is not sending a response with `BufferedWriter` out to the client. It seems as if the code stops at int `amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());` I believe the `bufferedreader.readline()` call on the client side is causing and issue and blocking the connection in some sense.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreadedConnection implements Runnable {

    private Socket connection;
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;

    public ThreadedConnection(Socket connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        try {
            this.in = this.connection.getInputStream();
            this.out = this.connection.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
        try {

            String lotteryType = bufferedReader.readLine(); //reads first line of input stream

            int amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
            System.out.println("3"+amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated);
            switch (lotteryType) {
                case "LuckyForLife":

                        generateLotteryNumbers(amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated, 48, 18, bufferedWriter);
                    break;
                case "MegaMillions":
                    generateLotteryNumbers(amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated, 70, 25, bufferedWriter);
                    break;
                case "PowerBall":
                    generateLotteryNumbers(amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated, 69, 26, bufferedWriter);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            bufferedWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void generateLotteryNumbers(int amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated, int upperLimitOfGeneratedNumbers, int upperLimitOfExtraNumber, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter){
        RandomNumberGenerator randomNumbers = new RandomNumberGenerator(amountOfNumbersToBeGenerated,upperLimitOfGeneratedNumbers);
        RandomNumberGenerator extraNumber = new RandomNumberGenerator(1,upperLimitOfExtraNumber);
        ArrayList randomNumbersArrayList = randomNumbers.NumberGenerator();
        ArrayList extraNumberArrayList = extraNumber.NumberGenerator();
        String randomNumbersString = randomNumbersArrayList.toString();
        randomNumbersString = randomNumbersString.substring(1, randomNumbersString.length()-1);
        String extraNumberString = extraNumberArrayList.toString();
        extraNumberString = extraNumberString.substring(1, extraNumberString.length()-1);

        try {
            bufferedWriter.write(randomNumbersString);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.write(extraNumberString);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//        System.out.println(randomNumbersString);
//        System.out.println(extraNumberString);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the client side. I think the first `String gerneretedNumber = bufferedReader.readLine();` is causing the issue. Almost as if it is called to read when there is nothing being written out from the server and then messing with the server side read. If I block both of the `readline()` calls the code on the server then works and I can get something to print out on console.

```
static void runClient(){
        OutputStream outputStream;
        InputStream inputStream;

        Socket client;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        try {
            System.out.println("Creating client socket ");
            client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);

            outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
            inputStream = client.getInputStream();
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            //bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            bufferedWriter.write("LuckyForLife");
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.write("5");
            bufferedWriter.flush();

            String generetedNumber = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String extraNumber = bufferedReader.readLine();

                System.out.println(gerneretedNumber);
                System.out.println(extraNumber);


            System.out.println("Guess its null");
            bufferedReader.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If anymore information is needed I am happy to post it.

Comment: It will help to restructure your code in such a way that the core logic accepts the pair of `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` instead of the socket. Then you can test your core logic independently of any sockets in a plain unit test piping data from one in memory container to another. When you know that work wrap it in a call with a socket and the chance the whole thing will work is very high.

Answer (score 0):

your client never sends the 2nd newline.
Given your protocol, client doesn't half close (output close) so the server cannot either detect end of stream.

BTW, try to close streams (tcp FIN) before close socket (tcp RST); it's more "ethical" ! Kidding aside, the tcp rst is a kill, and pending bytes might not be flushed out (although you have plenty of flushes here, it's just good practice).